# Calculating yesterday in JS on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, heroku

I'm trying to calculate how many day's in a row a user has performed an action. I do this by checking, every time I save said action, if the user did that action yesterday. But for some reason, this is not working on Heorku in Nodejs.

The code I'm running to compare the dates works fine in the browser:

```
var today = new Date();
var yesterday = new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
yesterday.setHours(0,0,0,0);
yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);

if( User.lastDate.getTime() === yesterday.getTime() ) {
  updateStreak();
} else {
  User.lastDate = today;
  resetStreak();
}
```

This test never returns true however. And I can't figure out why.

Comment: Lets try to understand your problem first. Very time a user dose something you update the time of the edit in the DB for the given user, is this correct?

Comment: What is the value of *User.lastDate*? What does *updateStreak* do?

Comment: @DavidGatti That's correct.

Comment: @RobG The value of lastDate is a date object, saved via the today variable at each update.
updateStreak just updates a value. It has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @JesperBylund—a date object is a type, not a value. *User.lastDate* must be initialised somehow (else `User.lastDate.getTime()` would fail with an error): how does that happen and what value is it set to?

Comment: @RobG It isn't. That is the code I'm using. You mean changing the IF to Date(User.lastDate).getTime() might solve the problem?

Comment: @JesperBylund—if *User.lastDate* is not initialised then the first time the code runs, it will be undefined. Trying to call a method of undefined should throw an error and stop the script executing. A fix is to first test *User.lastDate*: `if (User.lastDate && User.lastDate.getTime() === yesterday.getTime())`.

Comment: @RobG Oh now I get what you're asking. User is a model and has a default new Date() obj stored as lastDate.

Comment: Ok. So you set the time for *yesterday* to 00:00:00.0, do you do the same for *lastDate*? You say that the test doesn't evaluate to true, but don't show how that happens with actual values (see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).